# Wrong implementation for regex_constants in clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, std

As specified in the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type):

`match_prev_avail`: --first is a valid iterator position. When set, causes match_not_bol and match_not_bow to be ignored

But I run the following code and get:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex re0("^bcd");
    string str = "abcd";
    std::string::iterator start = str.begin() + 1;
    cout << regex_search(start, str.end(), re0, regex_constants::match_not_bol) << endl;
    cout << regex_search(start, str.end(), re0, regex_constants::match_prev_avail) << endl;
    cout << regex_search(start, str.end(), re0, regex_constants::match_prev_avail | regex_constants::match_not_bol) << endl;
}
```

output:

```
0
1
0
```

It seems that `match_prev_avail` is overwritten by `match_not_bol`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you found a bug in clang. (file it here: https://bugs.llvm.org/ as it seems not yet have been reported)

I checked MSVC 1914 and it gives

```
0
0
0
```

same as GCC 4.9.2 (used cpp.sh to check)

I rechecked the .pdf form of the standard (N4810) and this in 30.5.2 matches what the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type) states.

> match_prev_avail:
>   --first is a valid iterator position. When this flag is set the flags match_not_bol and match_not_bow shall be ignored by the regular expression
>   algorithms (30.11) and iterators (30.12)

Comment: Will you log this at bugs.llvm.org ?

Comment: i added the link for reporting, let the OP take credit, as he/she found it.

Comment: As I understand, `match_prev_avail` behaves the same as `match_not_bol `, right? Or to be more precise, `match_prev_avail` is equivalent to `match_not_bol | match_not_bow`?

Comment: @skeller I have reported it with ID 42199. Btw, what does "OP" mean? ^_^

Comment: @youkaichao https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OP#targetText=(Internet)%20Original%20poster%3B

Comment: @youkaichao thanks for finding and reporting the bug